# Jmeter: How can I keep 1000 or “X” users login requests session alive using JMeter?

Tags: testing, jmeter, load-testing, jmeter-plugins

Here is my Test Scenario:

First, I am generating a load which includes only Login Requests (say for 1000 users). I am using "Ultimate Thread Group" and "Constant Throughput Timer" in my script. `Constant Throughput Timer Value=120/sec` is used. I want to run this test for five or ten minutes. My load would be held for 3 minutes.

During this Test(while loads are held) , I am sending another set of login requests from the different machine (say for 100 users). I want to measure the response time of this 100 users login which I've generated from the different machine.

**But My Requirement is:** While I'm sending `100` users login requests, My Previous `1000` users login requests session should be alive on the server. I've also checked "`Use KeepAlive`" in my login sampler.

So, How can I achieve this?? How can I be sure that my previous all the login requests sessions are held on the server?

## Test Script:

Image 1: Screenshot for Ultimate Thread Group

[image]

Image 2: Screenshot for Constant throughput timer

[image]

Comment: Set the session timeout on your web server to ten minutes.   All you then need to do is issue a single session request and your session resource allocation if complete.  If you sign in then your sign in token expiration should be timed to your session expiration.   Then just run your 100 users.   Take the time to ramp them up from 1-100 to see what happens with each additional session increment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to consider following fields of ultimate thread group -

1. Shutdown time for 1000 threads ( ramp down time)
2. Hold load for - for 1000 threads.
3. Initial delay for 100 threads. ( time between starting the script and first server hit)
4. start time for 100 threads - make sure the 100 threads get ramp up before 1000 threads get shut down. Each thread would be start after ( start time/ start thread count ) seconds from the previous thread.

you need to configure these values in such a way that the first 1000 threads don't get shut down till the all of the next 100 users are active.

Also you can use the active thread over time graph which is provided with in the ultimate thread group to see how the many threads would be active.

P.S Don't confuse the thread number with number of requests, each thread will create multiple requests for seconds in  field " Hold Load for ".

Comment: I've already done this!!! But How can I be sure?? Is there any tool to see the sessions which are already live at any moment from the server??

Comment: Use active threads over time listener. Its available in Jmeters' Standard Set Plug-ins.

Comment: After running my test for 5 minutes, There are total (~31,000) Login requests for 1500 users. I held my load 60 seconds. It is obvious that those 1500 threads will be active or alive during "hold time" but my question is how many login requests (sessions) were alive that moment (during load held for 60 secs)??

All those requests (~31,000) were logged in with different username and password. I've also checked the report(View Results Tree) where all those requests session ids are different.
 So, are those all requests remained alive during the holding load time?

Comment: Hold Load for - means the threads would continue to hit the server i.e generate requests  for time mentioned in it. That's why you are getting multiple requests from the threads. Please note- total number of requests are related to throughput, Where as the number of active threads performing same activity are related to concurrency.

Comment: Improved the answer. Hope it answers your query :)

Comment: I've still some confusions on the "sessions".Actually,  I want to know how many login sessions are alive on that peak load time?? For my case, is it 1500 login sessions or 6000 (since load held for 60 secs at a rate 100/sec )??

Comment: share the jmeter script

Comment: Updated the question with Test Scripts Screenshots.